# Работа с БД при помощи JPA 2

Tags: jpa, java

Здравствуйте. Помогите, пожалуйста, разобраться, JPA 2.
Вопрос вот в чем:

Допустим, у меня есть некоторый класс, работающий с БД. Разные объекты его создают, используют и т.д. Чтобы не было много "мертвых" подключений, их постоянно надо закрывать.

```
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("commonStorage");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
// операции
em.close();
emf.close();
```

Но создание нового `EntityManager` занимает время. Может, есть что-то, что я упустил? Может, надо использовать один `EntityManagerFactory` на все приложение? Или другие варианты.

Comment: Быть может я конечно чегото недопонимаю но в php например (по нормальному) все что относится к базе это синглтон... Собственно а что вам мешает использовать его?<br>
<small><i>(Кроме религии java разрабов о том что статический метод должен ыть только один...)</i></small>

Comment: PHP-скрипт не работает бесконечно. Он запускается и завершается как только страница сгенерирована. Java веб-приложения выполняются в контейнере и приложение всё время подгружено и все запросы приходят в один процесс, тогда как в случае PHP запросы порождают новые процессы интерпретатора, работающие в разных контектсах. В связи с этим, для PHP это не актуально.

Comment: Обезопасится от создания лишних обьектов это не актуально?О_о<br>
Я крайне опечален вашим постом...<br><br>
А разницу между компилируемыми и скриптовыми языками я знаю, спасибо...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, **EntityManagerFactory** тяжеловесный объект и не стоит его создавать при каждом запросе. Лучше использовать стратегию - один **EntityManager** на один запрос.

Comment: Может наоборот?:)<br>
Один на все запросы?

Comment: Т.е. лучше всего создать синглтон? Т.е. один раз инициализировать `EntityManager` использовать его с постоянным удержанием подключения к базе данных?

Comment: Что думают остальные?

Comment: Разве не очевидно, что таким образом вы выигрываете в скорости приложения, причем заметно? Причем если нужно будет закрыть соединение - закройте, надо будет через время открыть - открывайте, но ИМХО это всегда должен быть единственный объект:

 * Во избежания ошибок (типа того, что вы приводили выше)
 * Во избежание излишеств, вида создания одних и тех же, которые по сути делает абсолютно одно и тоже, в существовании которых нет смысла.

Я в java не силен (мягко говоря), но по-моему абсолютно очевидно, что правильно делать именно так. Опять-таки в java я не силен, могу ошибаться, но вряд ли.

Comment: Я просто опасаюсь, что могут возникнуть некоторые проблемы, когда множество клиентов захотят попытаться получить доступ к одному `EntityManager`, а некоторые запросы могут длиться долго и ставить в остальных в очередь как-то некрасиво (когда, например, один человек ждет другого, а первому надо одна запись, в то время как другой делает выборку с подсчетами из 100 тыс.).

Comment: @Artem Prigoda прав, `EntityManager` легок и его стоит создавать на каждый юнит работы (<a href="http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/entitymanager/3.5/reference/en/html_single/#transactions-basics">см. второй абзац</a>, это для Hibernate). Кроме того, согласно вышеприведенным доками, он не является потокобезопасным в общем случае. Однако есть исключения: так, например, `EntityManager`, который был подключен из контекста спринга через `@PersistenceContext` будет потокобезопасным, так как в реальности будет подключен прокси, перенаправляющий запросы к текущему `EntityManager` или создающему новый.

Comment: JPA 2 Spec.: "An entity manager must not be shared among multiple concurrently executing threads, as the entity manager and persistence context are not required  to be threadsafe. Entity managers must only be accessed in a single-threaded manner." - так что это верно для всех реализаций, не только Hibernate.

Comment: Т.е., как я понял, `EntityManagerFactory` можно создавать один на все приложение, а для каждого отдельного клиента или операции, создавать свой `EntityManager`. Но он является потокобезопасным только через реализацию инъекции `@PersistenceContext`.  

Спасибо всем за советы. Поправьте меня, если не так понял.